# Gap Between tabular and caption* Inside table

Tags: tables, captions

I am inserting two `tabular`s in one `table` for Panels A and B. The `table` has one `caption`, and each `tabular` also has one `caption*` as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{SHORT TITLE}
\caption*{Panel A. LONG DESCRIPTION}
\begin{tabular}{*5c} \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%             I ALSO NEED A GAP HERE             %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\caption*{Panel B. LONG DESCRIPTION}
\begin{tabular}{*5c} \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And I found that the gap between the first `tabular` and the second `caption*` is too tight. The other three gaps (`caption`-`caption*`, `caption*`-`tabular`, `caption*`-`tabular`) are OK. Why do they have different gaps?

I also tried `subtable`s as follows, but still the tight gap looks ugly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{SHORT TITLE}
\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\centering
\subcaption{Panel A. LONG DESCRIPTION}
\begin{tabular}{*5c} \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%              STILL NO GAP APPLIED              %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\centering
\subcaption{Panel B. LONG DESCRIPTION}
\begin{tabular}{*5c} \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here I add my version (`\vspace{10pt}` for `\caption*` and `\vspace{6pt}` for `\subcaption*`) but don't know if best.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{SHORT TITLE}
\caption*{Panel A. LONG DESCRIPTION}
\begin{tabular}{*5c} \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}\vspace{10pt}

\caption*{Panel B. LONG DESCRIPTION}
\begin{tabular}{*5c} \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like subtables. What is supposed to be `\caption*` w.r.t. `\caption`?

Comment: I am using ```caption```s for short titles and ```caption*```s for long descriptions.

Comment: I think it would be semantically better to use subtables.

Comment: ```subtable```s show the same problem.

Comment: Try loading the `caption` package. When the caption is above the floating object, latex doesn't swap the values of \abovecaptionskip and \belowcaptionskip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this example will help.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{float}
\RequirePackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    
\centerline{SHORT TITLE}

    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering      
        \caption*{Panel A. LONG DESCRIPTION}
        \begin{tabular}{*5c} \hline
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}     
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                     I ALSO NEED A GAP HERE             %
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{table}[H]    
            \centering
        \caption*{Panel B. LONG DESCRIPTION}
        \begin{tabular}{*5c} \hline
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or this one: (you can also use `\subcaption*{⟨heading⟩}` )

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{FULL CAPTION}
    \begin{subtable}[t]{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
     \subcaption{    Panel A. LONG DESCRIPTION \\LONG DESCRIPTION }
        \begin{tabular}{*5c} \hline
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}%
    \begin{subtable}[t]{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
    \subcaption{  Panel B. LONG DESCRIPTION \\ LONG DESCRIPTION}
      \begin{tabular}{*5c} \hline
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE** after the comment. Put everything in a table environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{float}
\RequirePackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
      
\caption{SHORT TITLE 1}

    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering      
        \caption*{Panel A. LONG DESCRIPTION}
        \begin{tabular}{*5c} \hline
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}     
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                 I ALSO NEED A GAP HERE             %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{table}[H]    
        \centering
        \caption*{Panel B. LONG DESCRIPTION}
        \begin{tabular}{*5c} \hline
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{table}

\noindent ANOTHER GAP HERE    

\begin{table}[H] 
  
    \caption{SHORT TITLE 2}
    
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering      
        \caption*{Panel C. LONG DESCRIPTION}
        \begin{tabular}{*5c} \hline
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}     
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
PLUS ANOTHER GAP HERE               %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{table}[H]    
        \centering
        \caption*{Panel D. LONG DESCRIPTION}
        \begin{tabular}{*5c} \hline
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I need (1) my caption numbering unchanged and (2) my tables located vertically—I added my second version above.

Comment: @Junyong Kim Please my updated answer.

Comment: ```float``` works. Thank you.